# How to make middle div centered horizontally, inbetween elements floating to the left and right?

Tags: css

I would like the 'Middle' div below to be in the middle? Any ideas?

```
<div style="height:200px; width:100%">
<div style="float:left">Left</div>
<div>Middle</div>
<div style="float:right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto;` should do the trick if your div has a fixed-width.

Comment: Only if the `div` has a fixed-width.

Comment: Yep. I guess I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <p>Left Column</p>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <p>Right Column</p>
</div>

<div id="center">
    <p>Center Column</p>
</div>
```

​
And in your CSS:

```
div {background:#ff0;width: 200px;height: 500px;}
#right {float: right;}
#left {float: left;}
#center {background:#f00;margin: 0 auto;}​
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryancowles/YNWHe/

**Update**: You can wrap everything in `<div id="wrap"> <!-- Use the Above Code !--> </div>` and give the wrapping div a width with `#wrap {width:100%;}`

Comment: A live example is good, but you should also include the original code in your answer so that if the link breaks, your answer is still useful.

Comment: I should have thought of that.  Thanks for pointing it out!  I just added the markup to my original post.

Comment: Thanks for that but if I wrap a div around those three divs the code breaks?

Comment: Did you try giving that a shot?

Answer (score 0):

If your width is define you can write this:

```
.left{
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
.right{
    background:yellow;
    float:right;
}
.middle{
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/

}
.parent{
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
}
.parent div{
    text-align:left;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/9cBrh/1/

Comment: Hi in chrome the element on the right isn't level with the others. I am also wrapping my elemnts in a parent div like yours, which i think is causing the problem.